# "cargo +nightly contract build" ERROR: no path specified, and the default `src/main.rs` was not found

Tags: smart-contract, build, cargo

I am trying to use the `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build` command on a `cargo contract new ___`, but am experiencing the error below.

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.15s
 [2/5] Building cargo project
ERROR: No path specified, and the default `src/main.rs` was not found
```

The `cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract test` was executed successfully.

Can someone please help me understand why I'm seeing this error with a possible workaround please?
I guess another way to phrase my question is, where exactly from the root directory does the build command expect there to be a an "src/main.rs"?

Comment: Could you share your directory structure, and where you are building from? Also, double check if there is a parent directory with a Cargo.toml as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134990/cargo-would-not-build-even-when-src-main-rs-is-available

Comment: @PeterWhite resolved. My contract was nested in a parent containing a separate `Cargo.toml` file. All I did was move the contract folder out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving comment to answer:

> Double check if there is a parent directory with a Cargo.toml as outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134990/cargo-would-not-build-even-when-src-main-rs-is-available